# Python: Assign value to non-existing field

Tags: python

```
a = None
a.s = 2
```

throws an AttributeError. Is there a possibility to create an object a with the field s with value 2 without creating an own class for that? Would be super cool if Python would allow that hack! 8)

Comment: Python has builtins that would allow you to do this, but why not just make your own class? Just `class NameSpace: pass; a = NameSpace(); a.s = 2`

Comment: Honestly, that target duplicate is quite old, I wouldn't use a function object for that. You can use `from types import SimpleNamespace;  a = SimpleNamespace(); a.s = 2` or even `a = SimpleNamespace(s=2)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agreed, I added another target with more up-to-date answers.